# Staying Up to date with Github branches

Tags: git, github, branch

I have a project depending on some github branches/repos:

1. [**Docking ImGui**](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/tree/docking) the docking branch.
2. [**Node Repo**](https://github.com/thedmd/imgui-node-editor) which uses [**Master ImGui**](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/tree/master) with some **tweaks** I don't have in the docking branch.

What I did and I don't like is I created only one **Docking ImGui** folder (which I don't know what it tracks e.g. What is going to happen if I update that folder: I will lose all the tweaks) and I started making everything consistent manually copiying and pasting i.e. garbage.

**Now the question is**: Given the info above and this interbranch/repo mess, how can I have a one folder for ImGui that I can update using git simply without changing the files and copying pasting everywhere.

I think the question above specific but the generic question is: **How to stay up to date with repos (I know there is something called "fork", but I have no idea)**.

Could you please help me? My question might appear messy but I don't know what the right question to ask. Thank you!

Comment: Pick one branch to start developing from E.g. Master Imgui and then create your own branch from it To keep up-to-date with master you will need to rebase against it when you want to update with the latest changes there. I don't really understand why you think it is a mess and why folders seem so important to you. Looks like you need to read up a bit more on git before you continue.

Comment: Using git submodules might also help you

Comment: ***Will read a bit***. I am open to creating my own branches, however in this case, I need two repos in the same branch that use the same code i.e. Docking ImGui and Node Repo. I think it's the Node Repo who should have done it in a cleaner way and left the dependecies up to the user to install without cloning them her/himself..